Laptop shocks me only when connected to a USB-C monitor
I have a Dell U2520D monitor and an HP Pavilion Plus 14 laptop.
Both devices support power, data and display through USB-C.
When I use the laptop off battery or plugged in through the native (USB-C) charging brick, I never get shocked.
However, when I use it plugged in through the monitor (single cable for everything) and step away for even a few minutes, when I come back, 9 out of 10 times I get shocked when I touch it.
In both cases, I plug the device in to power through the Conair Travel Smart adapter.
I'm not worried about myself.
The shocks are mild.
I'm worried about the laptop, the monitor and any peripherals.
I don't know if this is at all related, but I have recently started noticing the monitor flickering, and it seems to be doing it more frequently after a particularly heavy shock or multiple frequent shocks.
Every place I've come across discussing this says it's completely harmless to electronics (unless it happens on a board directly), but I'm still skeptical, especially considering the seemingly increased monitor flickering.
Is it actually harmless, and, if not, how can I stop getting shocked?
Why does this only happen when charging through the monitor and not the native charger?

It sounds like the monitor is not properly grounded, but other than that, its not that big of a deal. I don't know how the monitor is getting its power, and if it normally has a ground on its connector or not. Not all monitors do, but some do require ground. Its also possible that the reverse is true. The monitor is properly grounded, but all other methods you use for charging is not. When you move away and come back, you yourself build up static electricity and you get shocked by discharging yourself through the ground of the monitor. Also, there may be a defect in the monitor.

@LPChip, it appears this is not an AC line shock, but due to static electricity, from the description. If so, that indicates the monitor is grounded.

@DrMoishePippik the part I'm confused about is it only happens when plugged in through the monitor. Shouldn't it also happen with the charging brick? Also, I'm really sorry, but I forgot to include a crucial detail which is that I'm using a travel adapter. I've updated my question.

One power supply could be effectively isolated, so that it does not pass a 20,000 VDC static shock to ground, and the other might be intentionally grounded. Only you know if the shock is jut static or AC leakage, edit and add that important fact to the question.

By "shocked", I assume you mean from static electricity, i.e., accumulation of a DC charge on your body as you slide off a chair or walk on the floor. Such a shock is a single pulse, and is not repeated even if you remove your hand from the PC and touch that spot again (without walking around again).
The first, static charge, is relatively innocuous. It won't hurt you, but it might destroy a device through electrostatic discharge (ESD). Most devices have some built-in ESD protection, though working on the innards of an electronic device and delivering ESD to its gizzards can destroy it.
To be safe, you might try one of these safety techniques:

Put a piece of metal connected to ground through a resistor or 200 kΩ or so near the PC, and touch that before touching the PC, to bleed off charge.
Use antistatic spray, such as is used to keep clothing or hair from sticking out. You might try it on your chair, the floor nearby, and other furniture.
When working inside the PC, e.g., changing RAM or SSD, use an anti-ESD wrist strap, such as these on Amazon.

The second type of "shock", a tingling or buzzing sensation that persists, is due to AC leakage.

It can be mild, due to high-frequency pulses from a switching power supply leaking out. Supplies connected to the AC mains with a two-prong plug may have that issue. Though just a nuisance, this high-frequency leakage can be grounded out. On an old Toshiba laptop, I put a 0.1 µF capacitor in parallel with a 220 kΩ resistor between the shell of the power supply DC connector and ground. (The capacitor grounds the AC, the resistor bleeds off any accumulated charge.)
It can also be due to a defective power supply, connecting you to the high side of the AC mains. This is potentially deadly. If the fix above does not remedy the issue, get a new power supply for the monitor, or have it serviced.

